# Show that a sequence converges to a limit (real analysis)

Tags: real-analysis, limits, convergence-divergence

let $u(m,n)_{m,n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a double sequence in $\mathbb{R}$ that converges uniformly to $v(n)$ in $\mathbb{R}$.

Suppose also that for each $m\in \mathbb{N}$ the sequence $u(m,n)$ has a limit in $\mathbb{R}$:

$lim_{n\to\infty} u(m,n) = w(m)$

And furthermore that: $lim_{m \to \infty} w(m) = \mathbb{l}$

Question/exercise: Show that $v(n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $\mathbb{l}$.

Now my approach was:

pick $m'$ large enough such that $w(m') = \mathbb{l}$ and $n'$ large enough such that $u(m',n') = w(m')$

and let $m''>m'$ be large enough such that

$u(m'',n') =v(n')$, but also such that

$u(m'',n') = w(m'') = \mathbb{l}$

and then, since uniform convergence:

$|u(m'',n')-v(n')| < \epsilon$ - (for any $\epsilon >0$) =

$|w(m'')-v(n')| < \epsilon$ =

$|\mathbb{l}-v(n')| < \epsilon$

$\iff$

$v(n') = \mathbb{l}$

Is this correct/sufficient?

Comment: Convergence does not mean that the sequence is eventually equal to the limit: $(1/n)_{n\geq1}$ converges to 0, but for no value of $n$ is $1/n=0.$

Comment: Is it possible to make some small change to fix that or is the entire idea wrong/useless?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let $\varepsilon>0.$ Choose $M$ such that $\forall m\geq M,$ $|w(m)-1|<\varepsilon/3.$ Now choose $M'\geq M$ such that $\forall m\geq M',$ $|u(m,n)-v(n)|<\varepsilon/3,$ for all $n$ (which is possible by uniform convergence). Choose $N$ such that for all $n\geq N,$ $|u(M',n)-w(M')|<\varepsilon/3.$ Then for these same $n,$ we have that $$|v(n)-1|\leq |v(n)-u(M',n)|+|u(M',n)-w(M')|+|w(M')-1|<\varepsilon,$$ so we have that $v(n)\rightarrow 1.$